# Pointer/Structure Issue C

Tags: c, pointers, constructor, segmentation-fault

I have the following code which segfaults, and I have absolutely no clue why. Any help would be very much appreciated.

The segfault happens when I do this (to check whether everything has been correctly initialised). Nothing is printed so it segfaults on the first line. Unfortunately I cannot use valgrind as this code is located within a sandbox which I can't access, so can't check the problem there.

```
for (i = 0 ; i<nb_read ; i++) {

 fprintf(stdout, "Read Lock i %d  %p \n ",i, nap->read_buffer[i]->sem_handle); 
 fprintf(stdout, "Write Lock i %d  %p \n ",i, nap->write_buffer[i]->sem_handle);  
 fprintf(stdout, "Read Buffer i %d  %p \n ",i, nap->read_buffer[i]->buffer); 
 fprintf(stdout, "Write Buffer i %d  %p \n ",i, nap->write_buffer[i]->buffer); 

}
```

where the SharedStruct is a struct with a char* buffer member and int sem_handle

```
SharedStruct** create_buffer(int nb, int size) {
SharedStruct** result = malloc(nb * sizeof(SharedStruct*));
int i = 0 ;
for (i = 0 ; i<nb ; i++) {
        SharedStruct* res= malloc(nb *sizeof(SharedStruct));
        res->buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(char)); 
        int lock = initialise_protection();
        fprintf(stdout, "\n Semaphore initialised to %d \n ", lock);
        res->sem_handle = lock ;
    }
    return result ;
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you compile it on your own machine and test it with `valgrind` there?

Comment: Also, what is `nap`, and where is it initialized? If `nap->read_buffer` is a `char` array, then of course this won't work. What would you expect the result to be if you did `'a'->sem_handle`?

Comment: Why this : SharedStruct* res= malloc(nb *sizeof(SharedStruct)); ?
I would say: result[i] = malloc(sizeof(SharedStruct));
+ what Gordon Bailey said

Comment: please show the code where create_buffer is called.

Comment: You don't know that the first fprintf fails, as it could be buffering the string and not printing it before the program ends. Also, you do not show the assignment of `nap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see you initializing the pointers contained in result. You just allocated space for them, seems you forgot to do result[i]=res inside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

First. You should indent the code correctly, otherwise you cannot read your own code.

Next, You initialize `result` as an array of `nb` entries, without initializing it at all.

Next, you alloc `nb` times a pointer to a (SharedStruct*), and for each such structure you alloc a buffer that you do not keep anywhere, hence you cannot free it later.